# Kubernetes local directory folder data not getting mounted to Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Here is the interesting part, the folders are getting mounted inside the pod but the files are not getting mounted inside the pod.

I am trying to do this in my deployment file-

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /fabric
      name: mypvc
    - mountPath: /host/var/run/docker.sock
      name: dockersocket
    - mountPath: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      name: msp-files
    - mountPath: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      name: tls-files

volumes: 

- name: mypvc
persistentVolumeClaim:
  claimName: mypvc
- name: dockersocket
hostPath:
  path: /var/run/docker.sock
- name: msp-files
hostPath:
  path: /home/dev-25-5/fabric/hyperledger/example.com/peer0/msp
- name: tls-files
hostPath:
  path: /home/dev-25-5/fabric/hyperledger/example.com/peer0/tls
```

Comment: Could you share more details about you k8s cluster ? Is it a standard 3-node GKE cluster ? Have you placed the required files in mentioned directories on every node ?

Comment: Yes, i have created the standard 3 node GKE cluster. Pardon my half knowledge, could you please tell, how can i check if i have mounted the directories on every node? this path /home/dev-25-5/fabric/hyperledger/example.com/peer0/msp is a local directory on my GKE. I have mounted my files under this directory.

Comment: I am following this link to create my nfs-server and pv - https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266

Comment: It's ok. If you use [HostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume type in k8s, your `Pods` are mounting the directories/files, which are present on your kubernetes nodes. So if you want to mount e.g. `/var/run/docker.sock` file into your `Pod`, such path must exist on your kubernetes node.

Comment: If you want to use [nfs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) storage, then the fragments from your deployment file that you shared in your question are incorrect. Take a look at [these](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs) example yaml files, specifically [this one](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/nfs-pv.yaml). As you can see you only need to specify your nfs server domain and `path:` to your files.

Comment: Thanks much for quick response. So are you suggesting fixing issue by taking one of approaches given above? am i mixing two approaches right now?

Comment: *"am i mixing two approaches right now?"* - yes, if you don't use `HostPath` as a volume type, you shouldn't use `hostPath:` key in your `deployment` definition yaml file. Note that in the tutorial you followed it isn't mentioned anywhere. Have you already configured your nfs server ? If yes, you just need to create PV and PVC like in the [example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nilesh93/101d620dfc409e89ca607a60eec36d80/raw/28d642c158103b5ee4cdffd7f7c410f4599f6a0b/pv-and-pvc-nfs.yml) given in the article and than refer to your PVC in your `Pod/Deployment` definition.

Comment: _"could you please tell, how can i check if i have mounted the directories on every node? "_ - where exactly do you placed your files ? Have you ssh-ed into every GKE node and make sure that required files are there ? _"this path /home/dev-25-5/fabric/hyperledger/example.com/peer0/msp is a local directory on my GKE"_ - What do you exactly mean by "local" ? When something is considered as _local_ for kubernetes it must exist on at least one of its nodes. But in the article you mentioned **gcePersistentDisk** is used instead of any local directories.

Comment: I have moved away from the hostpath approach, i am now using the NFS server, PV,PVC approach. I am able to mount the data from /export path from the NFS server to the pod container path, this works well for the single mountpath, but now i want to mount multiple subdirectories of /export, to my multiple mount path in pod deployment. getting errors while doing that. looks like some limitation with the NFS server image on GKE.

Comment: You may consider asking a separate question regarding this new problem as it isn't related with the original topic. Maybe it can be solved as well but you need to provide some details.